# How to block Windows from automatically installing some USB devices as trusted

Tags: windows, usb

As stated in one of the answers to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102873/how-can-usb-sticks-be-dangerous), operating systems seem to automatically install "keyboard" USB devices as trusted.

Since the OS gets the USB device type from the device itself, this makes it possible to create USB devices that declare themselves as e.g. "keyboard" type while actually being something else.

It seems that one of the answers to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64524/how-to-prevent-badusb-attacks-on-linux-desktop?lq=1) explains how to block Linux from automatically installing HID devices.

Is there a way to block Windows from automatically installing USB devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what your looking for, but please note this is for Windows 7 as you did not specify what version of Windows:

To disable Windows 7’s ability to automatically detect and install drivers, here’s a step that may help.

**Step 1:**

1. Go to Start > Control Panel.
2. Type Change device installation settings.
3. Click on the link Change device installation settings under Devices and Printers.
4. Under “Do you want Windows to download driver software and realistic icons for your devices?”, click on “No, let me choose what to do”.
5. Select “Never install driver from Windows Update”. The system will always ask you to provide the device driver.
6. Save the changes.

**Step 2: Via Group Policy editor.**

Note: Group policy editor is available only in Professional, Ultimate and Enterprise edition of Windows 7.**(GPEDIT.MSC)** You will not have the Local Group Policy Editor available in the Windows 7 Starter and Home Premium editions.

Also note that you should have administrative privileges to perform these tasks.

1. Go to Start and then in the Start Search box, type mmc gpedit.msc.
2. In the navigation pane, open the following folders: Local Computer Policy, Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, Driver Installation.
3. Double-click Turn Off Windows Update Device Driver Search Prompt in the right side of the window.
4. Go to the Setting tab of the dialog box.
5. Select the Enable radio button.
6. Click Apply and then click OK.
7. Close Local Group Policy Editor.

**To block USB Storage Devices:**

You need to use GPEDIT.MSC

Computer Configuration –> Administrative Templates –> System –>Device Installation –> Device Installation Restrictions

set up the policy for: “Prevent installation of removable devices”